# Gunicorn + Nginx - Resource temporarily unavailable while connecting to upstream

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gunicorn, supervisord

We are using gunicorn + supervisor + nginx to run django app using docker environment on beanstalk

Issue is supervisor shows that gunicorn is up but all requests fails with 502 response code from nginx. Gunicorn process doesn't recover even when there is no traffic on the instance.

Ideally I think supervisor should restart gunicorn process since it's not able to respond any request successfully.

Load: ~1700 Requests per min/instance - c6a.large instance

```
server_tokens off;

upstream wsgi_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).

  server unix:/run/django_app.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $http_x_forwarded_proto;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
      proxy_read_timeout 60s;
      proxy_pass http://wsgi_server;
  }
}
```

```
2022/10/10 12:35:26 [error] 21#21: *728396 connect() to unix:/run/django_app.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.53.68, server: *.service.vpc, request: "GET /user/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/django_app.sock:/user/", host: "service.vpc"
```

Additionally, How to debug hanged gunicorn worker to figure out where exactly the problem lies ?